# How to display the values after submit in drupal 7

Tags: 7

I have a three form fields like Name,phone,email now after inserting the values in my db i want to display the values into same page or another page like
 Name:XXXXXXXXXXX
 Phone:5545445454
 email:yyy@some.com

how can do this in drupal7

Comment: Is it about custom form and custom table in DB?

Comment: @Xio is it like custom form

Comment: @user22455 updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) to do that.

Just replace the `FORM_ID` with the `ID` of your form.
Lets say the id of the form is `my_custom_form`, then the values could be printed as,

```
function MODULE_form_my_custom_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  //add a new function(submit handler) on submit button.    
  $form['#submit'][] = 'new_submit_function';
}

function new_submit_function(&$form, &form_state) {
  // the $form_state['values'] array contains all the 
  // values from the fields of the current form stored in it
  drupal_set_message("name : " . $form_state['values']['name']);
  drupal_set_message("phone : " . $form_state['values']['phone']);
  //and so on.
  //the message will be displayed on the page after form submit
}
```

If you are not sure how to find the id of the form, then use [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to do that, e.g.

```
function MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  drupal_set_message($form_id);
}
```

this would print the form id of every form you are on, so that you can use the id of the form you wish to change and perform a `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter` to change anything you wish :-)

Answer (score 1):

If it is a custom form then in the submit function where you are inserting the records to the database, you can print the values on that page also. All the values of the form are in the `$form_state` array.

You can display the values in `drupal_set_message()` function or using the `theme()` function.

OR if you want to display the values on another page after submit then you should define the action for your form like `$form['#actions'] = url('node/xxx')`.

Comment: How can i post the values to next page

Comment: when you set the form action to that page, the form values automatically posted to that page when you submit the form.